# Program hangs with smaller integers

Tags: c

I'm having issues with the code pasted below where it just hangs during runtime.  VS2010 doesn't give me any warnings or errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void clear_buffer(void)
{
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}

int validate(int low, int high) {
    int num;

    scanf("%d", &num);
    while(num < low || num > high) 
    {
        clear_buffer();
        printf("INVALID! Must enter value between %d and %d: ", low, high);
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    return num;
}

int getRand(int max) {
    int number;
    number = rand() % max + 1;
    return number;
}

int validatePick(int pick, int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) {
    int valid = 0;

    if (pick != one && pick != two && pick != three && pick != four && pick != five) {
        valid = 1;
    } else {
        valid = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}
void prnt(int qty, int one, int two, int three, int four, int five, int six) {
    int i = 0, flag = 0;
    while (flag != 2) {
        flag = 0;
        if (sort2(&one, &two) == 0 && sort2(&three, &four) == 0 && sort2(&five, &six) == 0)
            flag = 1;
        if (sort2(&two, &three) == 0 && sort2(&four, &five) == 0)
            flag = 1;
        flag += flag;
    }

    printf("Picks: %d, ", one);
    while (i <= qty){
        if (i== 2 && qty == 2)
            printf("%d\n", two);
        else if (i == 2 && qty != 2) 
            printf("%d, ", two);

        if (i == 3 && qty == 3) 
            printf("%d\n", three);
        else if (i == 3 && qty != 3) 
            printf("%d, ", three);

        if (i == 4 && qty == 4)
            printf("%d\n", four);
        else if (i == 4  && qty != 4)
            printf("%d, ", four);

        if (i == 5 && qty == 5)
            printf("%d\n", five);
        else if (i == 5  && qty != 5) 
            printf("%d, ", five);

        if (i == 6 && qty == 6) 
            printf("%d\n", six);
        i++;
    }
}



int sort2(int *n1, int *n2) {
    int tmp, valid = 0;

    if (*n1 > *n2)
    {
        tmp = *n2;
        *n2 = *n1;
        *n1 = tmp;
        valid = 1;
    }
    return valid;
}

int main () {
    int num1, num2;
    int pick, one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0, five = 0, six = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("LOTTERY GENERATOR\n");
    printf("Enter the maximum value between 1 and 100: ");
    num1 = validate(2,100);
    printf("Enter quantity of numbers to pick, between 1 and 6: ");
    num2 = validate(1, 6);

    one = getRand(num1);
    while (two == 0 || three == 0 || four == 0 || five == 0 || six == 0) {
        pick = getRand(num1);
        if (validatePick(pick, one, two, three, four, five) == 1 && two == 0)
            two = pick;
        else if (validatePick(pick, one, two, three, four, five) == 1 && three == 0)
            three = pick;
        else if (validatePick(pick, one, two, three, four, five) == 1 && four == 0)
            four = pick;
        else if (validatePick(pick, one, two, three, four, five) == 1 && five == 0)
            five = pick;
        else  if (validatePick(pick, one, two, three, four, five) == 1)
            six = pick;
    }
    prnt(num2, one, two, three, four, five, six);
}
```

If I enter say 3 for `Enter the maximum value between 1 and 100` and then 2 the program just hangs.  I don't understand why it does such.  I don't see an error in the code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in your logic.  If I understand the program correctly, you are trying to pick 6 different numbers, randomly generated in the range from `1` to `num1`.

Now here's the problem:  Your `while` loop only terminates when all six variables (`one`, `two`.. `six`) are not `0`.  The only way that one of these variables can be set to a non-zero value is if `validatePick` returns `1`, and *that* can only happen if the random number generated has not already been assigned to one of `one`, `two`... `six`.

This boils down to something like a reverse pigeon-hole problem; you are trying to fill six pigeon-holes with less than six pigeons, an impossible task.

If `num1` is less than `6`, then its impossible for you to satisfy the termination condition of your while loop, and your program will seemingly hang.

You can verify this by putting an `else` case in your while loop and printing what random number you generated, and also printing what the value for each variable is at each iteration.

Note that your second input, `num2`, is not referenced in any way until after your `while` loop, so the value you enter there will not be able to limit the number of unique random values your program tries to generate.

Comment: The issue is, I can't print what the variable is holding because it hangs after the 2nd input.

Comment: Where are you trying to print it?  I added an `else` statement in the while loop and can print all the variables.

Comment: hmm  I just added the print to the end of the loops, (endless loop btw is the issue).  Shouldn't all the variables be filled with a random number, even though I am only requesting 2 numbers from a max 3?

Comment: if you try to pick 3 unique integers, but only have a pool of 2 integers to work with, you cannot succeed.  This should end up as an additional input validation check, I think.

Comment: h,mm that is correct, i'll have to see if they want this or not.  It may be the case they want only true lottery picks and not something else.  Thanks for the help I see the issue now.

Comment: @LucaTenuta Your loop condition always requires that all 6 variables are filled.  Your second input is only used to cull the number of random numbers that you print.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to buffering.  Note that if `3` is entered, the check passes and `clear_buffer` is not called.  Try changing the function so that it's called after the input even.

This is why I don't like `scanf` so much -- it's so easy to lose track of the state of the buffer, and find your program stuck in a loop.  I prefer to read a whole line, using, say, `fgets`, then tokenise it and parse it myself.  For a simple program like this it's pretty easy using `strtol` or even just `atoi`.  At least this way I have more direct visibilty of all the many edge-cases of input.